# Convert mach absolute timestamp to NSDate

Tags: swift

I have a mach absolute timestamp from a sql database, I want to read in my app. I want to display this timestamp, so I want to convert it to NSDate. How is this possible? I have a timestamp like this: `443959550` (result in this case is UTC: `26.01.2015 10:05:50`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`443959550` seems to be a time interval since the reference date
1 January 2001, GMT:

```
let date = NSDate(timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate: 443959550)
println(date) // 2015-01-26 10:05:50 +0000
```

Comment: You'll never stop learning... I didn't knew, that there is a second reference date between 1970 ;) That's the right answer, thank you very much!

Comment: @Lupurus: Actually that is what NSDate internally uses, see https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDate_Class/.

Comment: That's interesting. So older dates have a negative timestamp? What's so special with 1.1.2001?

Comment: @Lupurus: Yes. – I don't know.

Comment: I think the question needs to be updated to reflect the wrong assumption of "mach absolute time" that number is NOT mach absolute time (which is measured in hardware-specific number of clock-cycles since the machine was turned on).

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at [`timeIntervalSince1970`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDate_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSDate/initWithTimeIntervalSince1970:). There you can set a timestamp as init-parameter.

```
var timeStamp = 443959550
//NSDate
var date = NSDate(timeIntervalSince1970:443959550)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but the result in this case is: `26.01.1984 11:05`. The years are not correct.